# DbUpdateException upon deleting entity with navigation properties using lazy loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to remove it this way:

```
var myEntity = await db.MyEntities.FindAsync(id);

if (myEntity != null)
{
    db.MyEntities.Remove(myEntity);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And it's giving me this error:

```
An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships
```

If I manually `.Include()` the navigation properties, it works fine.

My question is two fold, why is Lazy Loading not loading whatever properties are necessary for this to just work, and is there a proper way to remove entities without having to manually `.Include()` every single navigation property beforehand?

Comment: What is the execution environment of this? ASP.NET?

Comment: MVC 5, i'll add the tag

Comment: I think I found my problem, db was probably in no shape to lazy load anything by the time I do db.SaveChangesAsync(). If I create a new db context just before doing so it works fine. It would still be nice if there was a way to just delete it without the context bothering with the values of the navigation properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as I suspected, lazy loading wasn't working anymore because the dbcontext was either closed or in some closing state. I fixed all my problems by switching to a singe  DbContext per request (stored in HttpContext.Current.Items)